# Android: How to merge 2 AttributeSet objects?

Tags: android

I have 2 AttributeSet objects- how can I combine them into 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create a [MutableAttributeSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MutableAttributeSet.html) and then add each element from your two existing ones to it?

Comment: The title is marked as Android. I don't think that class exist in android.